# How to add a Total row in a magento grid

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, grid, grid-serlization

I'm creating a new module that uses a order grid for  particular product(this is not the report grid) in magento admin i successfully create new order grid for that but i want to get total price for product at the end , like in sales>report.

Please see image

[image]

Any help will be appreciated,,Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what are you trying to achieve, but as a good starting point you can look at Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Grid::_afterLoadCollection(). On line 58 (Magento 1.7.0.2 CE) this method instantiates and populates Mage_Reports_Model_Totals(). Take a look at this class. Also check this Magestore article about total models : http://blog.magestore.com/2012/09/07/magento-blogcertificate-total-models/

Comment: Hello @Keyur shah have you done with this?can you please answer[THIS](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15123/how-to-add-a-column-total-row-in-a-magento-grid-at-the-end) how can i add total at the end of grid?

Comment: @Freedom i am achieving this . you can add total using overriding sales/grid.php and add below code by mazeUz

Comment: Thanks got it.but it does not display 'Totals' title as seen on the below image instead it display checkbox.Require any changes in the code?

Comment: @Freedom can you please check my answer ?

Comment: Hello I have used this code but cannot get the word TOTAL described when the grid is exported to CSV

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1.Sipmle way,** add these fields to your gird class, see mine:

```
class SSD_Uzkart_Block_Adminhtml_Uzkart_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    protected $_countTotals = true;

    public function getTotals()
    {
        $totals = new Varien_Object();
        $fields = array(
            'uzkart_trans_amount' => 0, //actual column index, see _prepareColumns()
            'some_summarable_field' => 0,
            'another_countable_field' => 0,
        );
        foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
            foreach($fields as $field=>$value){
                $fields[$field]+=$item->getData($field);
            }
        }
        //First column in the grid
        $fields['entity_id']='Totals';
        $totals->setData($fields);
        return $totals;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        /**
         * another columns
         */

        $this->addColumn('uzkart_trans_amount', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('uzkart')->__('Payment Amount'),
            'index' => 'uzkart_trans_amount',
            'type' => 'currency',
        ));

        /**
         * another columns
         */
    }

    /**
     * another methods
     */

}
```

**My Result**
[image]

**2.Using Magento Reports: (But this one is so complicated)**

You should create report grid. See `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Customer_Orders_Grid` report grid and try to impelement own. Here is great tuts about custom reports:
http://codegento.com/2011/03/creating-custom-magento-reports
http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/custom-reports-magento

Comment: thanks for your answer it help me a lot +1 for it @mageUz

Comment: boom Finally it works flawlessly big thank you @mageUz

Comment: Hello I have used this code but cannot get the word TOTAL described when the grid is exported to CSV .

Comment: Hello, This worked for me but I am not able to get total of columns which are using Renderer.

Answer (score 7):

mageUz's answer is really good and simple.

I had some problems with the "action" column showing in totals row so I looked into it a bit further. So here it is...

**1. Hide the Action Column in totals** and more

Due to probably a bug in `widget/grid.phtml` the `'is_system'` parameter is not taken under consideration, so it shows the action link in the totals row. In order to solve it, just add  `'totals_label' => '',`  in your action column declaration.

The  `'totals_label' => 'label',` parameter can be used in all columns and it will override the totals cell even if it's set.

That said you can omit the `$fields['entity_id']='Totals';` line of mageUz's answer, go to the 'entity_id' column (or any column you choose) and add

`'totals_label' => $this->__('Total'),` (+multilingual support)

**2. Same result, slightly different approach**

In your grid block add a protected function _prepareTotals($columns). Then call it in the _prepareCollection() function with the rows you want as totals comma separated. To be more clear your Whatever/Grid.php should look something like this

```
protected function _prepareCollection(){
  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('mymodule/mymodel_collection');
  $this->setCollection($collection);
  $this->_prepareTotals('price,special_price'); //Add this Line with all the columns you want to have in totals bar
  return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

//Add following function
protected function _prepareTotals($columns = null){
  $columns=explode(',',$columns);
  if(!$columns){
    return;
  }
  $this->_countTotals = true;   
  $totals = new Varien_Object();
  $fields = array();
  foreach($columns as $column){
    $fields[$column]    = 0;    
  } 
  foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
    foreach($fields as $field=>$value){
      $fields[$field]+=$item->getData($field);
    }
  }
  $totals->setData($fields);
  $this->setTotals($totals);
  return;
}

protected function _prepareColumns(){
  $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
    'index'             => 'entity_id',
    'header'            => $this->__('ID'),
    'totals_label'      => $this->__('Total'), //Add this line to show "Total" in the beginning of the row
  ));

  $this->addColumn('name', array(
    'index'             => 'name',
    'header'            => $this->__('Name'),
  ));

  $this->addColumn('price', array(
    'index'             => 'price',
    'header'            => $this->__('Price'),
    'type'              => 'currency',
    'currency_code'     => $this->_getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
  ));

  $this->addColumn('special_price', array(
    'index'             => 'special_price',
    'header'            => $this->__('Special Price'),
    'type'              => 'currency',
    'currency_code'     => $this->_getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
  ));

  $this->addColumn('action',array(
    'header'        => $this->__('Action'),
    'width'         => '100',
    'type'          => 'action',
    'getter'        => 'getId',
    'actions'       => array(array(
                          'caption' => $this->__('edit'),
                          'url'     => array('base' => '*/*/edit'),
                          'field'       => 'product_id',
                      )),
    'filter'        => false,
    'sortable'      => false,
    'is_system'     => true,
    'totals_label'      => '' //Add this line to stop the action showing 
  ));
  return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Comment: Using this method it seems that the total from exported CSV file doesn't contain the right data. What should be in total row is from first row from grid.