# How to add a column Total row in a magento grid at the end

Tags: order-grid, totals

How to display total row at the end of sales order grid.see below image

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

source [How to add a Total row in a magento grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/how-to-add-a-total-row-in-a-magento-grid)

thanks to [@mazeUz](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2248/mageuz)

first you have override `sales/grid.php`

then if you want to add total row then add below code

```
class SSD_Uzkart_Block_Adminhtml_Uzkart_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    protected $_countTotals = true;

    public function getTotals()
    {
        $totals = new Varien_Object();
        $fields = array(
            'uzkart_trans_amount' => 0, //actual column index, see _prepareColumns()
            'some_summarable_field' => 0,
            'another_countable_field' => 0,
        );
        foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
            foreach($fields as $field=>$value){
                $fields[$field]+=$item->getData($field);
            }
        }
        //First column in the grid
        $fields['entity_id']='Totals';
        $totals->setData($fields);
        return $totals;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        /**
         * another columns
         */

        $this->addColumn('uzkart_trans_amount', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('uzkart')->__('Payment Amount'),
            'index' => 'uzkart_trans_amount',
            'type' => 'currency',
        ));

        /**
         * another columns
         */
    }

    /**
     * another methods
     */

}
```

**[EDIT]**

**if it display check box rather then label Total then you have to first check it must match with first column grid id** if it's your `increment_id` then it must be

```
$fields['increment_id']='Totals';
```

[image]

Comment: I have changed to 'increment_id' but still it display checkbox.

Comment: @Freedom not increment_id you have to set first column id. is increment_id your first column?

Comment: `$this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));` First column

Comment: when i changed to 'real_order_id' it's doesn't display Totals label

Comment: is increment_id your first column ?

Comment: yes increment_id is my first column .

Comment: can you show your grid.php?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13079/discussion-between-freedom-and-keyur-shah)