# magento 2 Add totals row at end of the grid

Tags: magento2, grid

> Note: I am not using ui component to create my grid

I want to show totals at the end of the grid:
[image]

I got stack exchange question related to this, but its for Magento 1.9

[How to add a column Total row in a magento grid at the end](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15123/how-to-add-a-column-total-row-in-a-magento-grid-at-the-end)

Can anyone would help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Grid.php` file added a `protected` variable on class level

```
protected $_countTotals = true;
```

then add a function

```
public function getTotals()
{
    $totals = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject;
    $fields = array(
        'sold_count' => 0,
        'unit_price' => 0,
        'total_amount' => 0
    );
    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        foreach($fields as $field=>$value){
            if($field == "position" || $field == "total_limit") {
                $fields[$field] += $item->getData($field);
            }
        }
    }
    //First column in the grid
    $fields['id']='Totals';
    $totals->setData($fields);
    return $totals;
}
```

**I hope this will help**